# How do I fix the missing reboot/shutdown issue in 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, power-management, shutdown, bug-reporting, restart

I am one of the unfortunate who has the problem in 13.10 whereby my reboot/shutdown button is missing from the menu bar.

After googling around I found the bug being submitted but the fixes (which apparently didnt work) looked like manually downloading all sorts of Ubuntu source codes and lots of other scary stuff.

Is there anything I can enter/update from the terminal which will fix this issue of the missing shutdown/restart menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        dconf reset -f "/home/yourusername/"
```

note: must use / in the end of the path

dconf is what holds all of the values and defaults factors for Unity thus, that's what controls the reboot/shutdown buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS and experienced the same problem (hopefully this fix will work for you too), my menu didn't show "Restart" and "Shutdown" anymore.

I installed https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/dconf-tools/.
In the left tree select `apps > indicator-session` and check/uncheck the following options:

- Check `suppress-logout-menuitem`
- Check `suppress-logout-restart-shutdown`
- Uncheck `suppress-restart-menuitem`
- Uncheck `suppress-shutdown-menuitem`

With these settings the "Restart" and "Shutdown" options appear again in the top right menu.