# Ubuntu 14.04 shutdown and restart missing

Tags: unity, 14.04, shutdown

After fresh clean install when i click right top gear icon and select shutdown from menu then a window appears with two big buttons:

- restart
- shutdown

Now if i click right top gear icon and select shutdown from menu then a window appears with two big buttons:

- lock
- logout

no shutdown nor restart

Want to restore the original behavior, restart and shutdown, need not lock and logout

Answer (score 2):

## The solution

---

You can try resetting your `dconf` settings by running the following command:

```
dconf reset -f "/home/yourusername/"
```

Note the trailing slash, it's important.

Backup:

If this doesn't work for whatever reason, try running:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/dconf/user
```

## How it works

---

`dconf` contains all of the relevant infomation about controlling Unity. It contains menu actions, dock associations, and many different things. Clearing it forces Unity to rebuild all  of it's configs. However, clearing this (while it may fix your problem) may result in the loss of your Unity personal settings. Be careful please!

[(src)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389332/how-do-i-fix-the-missing-reboot-shutdown-issue-in-13-10)

Comment: Thanks fast response. Typed command above did not reset any config but realized it is a missconfiguration in dconf. Deleted file `~/.config/dconf/user` and restart - personal settings gone. All fine now, shutdown and restart buttons are back. Have to redo personal settings not a big deal.

Comment: That works too :D